# Content wider than page which scrolls horizontally in WinRT App

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

How could I achieve a page layout in which I could scroll horizontally to the right, to display a content on the page that is wider than the page itself? Something very similar to the "Store" App...

Tried scrollviewer encasing stackpanel, grids or others and no result. I looked at the samples  that are generated from the Store project templates but those are also different. I guess it shouldn't be so hard but can't figure it out...

I'm trying to obtain something like this : [image]

I want to display a content, divided into columns, which continues from a column to another. Tried also with WrapGrid, but no success...  Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going implement something similar to Article view, please read this page [News apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868272.aspx) on MSDN. It gives you information about what should you use to build apps like News apps, check the *Your app's article view* part:

> For more info about best practices for fonts, such as size, color, and
>   weight, see Guidelines and checklist for text and typography
>   (JavaScript) or Displaying and editing text (C#/VB/C++). In Windows
>   Store apps written using XAML, you can use the RichTextBlock and
>   RichTextBlockOverflow controls to manage text overflow. For an
>   example, see [XAML text display sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-text-display-sample-2593ba0a).